# minecraft launcher not opening forge

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

when I try to open forge from the minecraft launcher, it doesn't load. I even did it without mods and it still didn't work. This is what I got from the game output:

```
[14:11:24] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[14:11:24] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[14:11:24] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[14:11:24] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 7.10.1.1160 for Minecraft 1.7.10 loading
[14:11:24] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_25, running on Mac OS X:x86_64:10.10.1, installed at /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
[14:11:24] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[14:11:24] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[14:11:24] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[14:11:24] [main/ERROR] [LaunchWrapper]: Unable to launch
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:865) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:117) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
```

I'm using 1.7.10 forge. i got the latest forge (10.13.2.1230) and it still doesn't work.

Mods:

- Bibliocraft
- Assassins Craft
- parachute
- buildcraft
- mocreatures
- minions mod
- more nature
- nuclear bomb mod

PC Specifications:

- iMac 24-inch, early 2008
- 2.8 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- 4 GB 800 MHz DDR2 SDRAM
- ATI Radeon HD 2600 Pro 256 MB

Comment: Do you get the same error message when you try to run it without mods?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft. We only support vanilla Minecraft in terms of tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Forge doesn't play well with recent versions of Java. Java 1.8.20 fixed a bug in the language runtime that was hiding a bug in Forge, so if you want to continue using Forge you need to either:

- Downgrade to an earlier version of Java, preferably the latest in the 1.7 branch; or
- Download [this .jar](http://files.minecraftforge.net/LegacyJavaFixer/legacyjavafixer-1.0.jar) and place it in your Forge mod folder.